# How we can change the name of a PDF in ninja forms by using any field value from form submitted

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

How we can change the PDF name in Ninja forms by the field value from form which is submitted

Answer (score 1):

With the new version of ninja-forms:

```
function custom_pdf_name( $name, $sub_id ) {
    $sub = Ninja_Forms()->form()->get_sub( $sub_id );
     $name = $sub->get_field_value('title_1542019981951') . $sub_id;
     return $name;
  }
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submission_pdf_name', 'custom_pdf_name', 20, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_pdf_name( $name, $sub_id ) { 

     global $ninja_forms_processing;
     $form_id= $ninja_forms_processing->get_form_ID();
     $value1 = $ninja_forms_processing->get_field_value( 110 );//110 is id of the field we want to attach with the name of PDF

   if($form_id=='11'){ //11 is id of the form submitted
   $name = 'Form Name -' . $value1;
   }
     return $name; 
  } 
add_filter( 'ninja_forms_submission_pdf_name', 'custom_pdf_name', 20, 2 );
```